# Connecting to background EventMachine application for unit testing

Tags: ruby, macos, sockets, eventmachine

I am writing a headless Ruby application using [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) that communicates over sockets. I want to write some unit tests for this app. This means that my Ruby test script needs to launch that app in the background, perform socket communication with it, and then close that process.

This code fails. The socket connection is refused.

```
require 'socket'
PORT = 7331
CMD = File.expand_path("../../bin/rb3jay",__FILE__)
@thread = Thread.new{ `#{CMD} -D --port #{PORT}` }
@socket = TCPSocket.open('localhost', PORT)
#=> Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 7331
```

If I inject a 2 second delay before attempting the socket connection, it works as desired:

```
@thread = Thread.new{ `#{CMD} -D --port #{PORT}` }
sleep 2
@socket = TCPSocket.open('localhost', PORT)
```

This seems a gross hack. Maybe 2 seconds is long enough for my machine, but too short somewhere else.

How should I correctly launch my EventMachine application in the background, and create a socket connection to it as soon as it is ready?

Comment: I had considered using EventMachine as a client in my unit test file instead of the standard Ruby `socket` library, but I cannot figure out how to use its event loop along with `MiniTest::Unit` in a way that allows me to re-establish the server and connection before each test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there's a better way, but I solved this by using `retry`:

```
@thread = Thread.new{ `#{CMD} -D --port #{PORT}` }
begin
  @socket = TCPSocket.open('localhost', PORT)
rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
  sleep 0.1
  retry
end
```

This will indefinitely keep trying to establish the connection 10 times a second until it works. A more robust solution might be to use a counter or timer to eventually give up, just in case something is seriously awry.

The full test code looks like this:

```
require 'socket'
require 'minitest/autorun'

PORT = 7331
CMD = File.expand_path("../../bin/rb3jay",__FILE__)

class TestServer < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @pid = Process.spawn "#{CMD} -D --port #{PORT}"
    begin
      @socket = TCPSocket.open('localhost', PORT)
    rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
      sleep 0.1
      retry
    end
  end

  def teardown
    if @socket && !@socket.closed?
      @socket.puts("quit") # try for a nice shutdown
      @socket.close
    end
    Process.kill("HUP",@pid)
  end

  def test_aaa
    # my test code
  end

  def test_bbb
    # more test code
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that from the main thread you can't know when `Thread.new` code block has actually been executed. By using `sleep`, you just give it enough time so it is executed.

In such cases, I prefer to use a `Queue`, where the `Thread.new` block does a `push` (usually a `nil`) into it after it has finished doing what it's supposed to do, while the thread that used to `sleep`, does a `pop` from it. `pop` waits until there are data available in the `Queue`.

```
require 'socket'
PORT = 7331
CMD = File.expand_path("../../bin/rb3jay",__FILE__)
q = Queue.new
@thread = Thread.new do
  Process.spawn "#{CMD} -D --port #{PORT}"
  q.push(nil)
end
q.pop
@socket = TCPSocket.open('localhost', PORT)
```

However, you might face problems, since spawning your command doesn't mean that the server is actually ready (listening for new connections). So, I'd try an approach were I could have more control over the life-cycle of the server.

```
require 'socket'
PORT = 7331
q = Queue.new
@thread = Thread.new do
  server = TCPServer.new PORT
  q.push(nil)

  loop do
    client = server.accept
    client.puts "Hello !"
    client.puts "Time is #{Time.now}"
    client.close
  end
end
q.pop
@socket = TCPSocket.open('localhost', PORT)
```